# Uncaught ErrorException , migrating from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7

Tags: php, exception

Hello i am trying to migrate my web browser game from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.0.23.
Now i am stuck here and get errors in my exceptionHandler function. 
I tested with PHP 5.6 and my page works, but when i change PHP to 7 it displays error. 
I look in PHP homepage and did not find anything or i probably missing something.

This is the full Function:

```
function exceptionHandler($exception) 
{
    global $CONF, $USER;
    if(!headers_sent()) {
        if (!class_exists('HTTP', false)) {
            require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'includes/classes/HTTP.class.php');
        }       
        HTTP::sendHeader('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable');
    }   

    if(method_exists($exception, 'getSeverity')) {
        $errno  = $exception->getSeverity();
    } else {
        $errno  = E_USER_ERROR;
    }

    $f = fopen(ROOT_PATH.'includes/errors.txt', 'ab');  

    $errorType = array(
        E_ERROR             => 'ERROR',
        E_WARNING           => 'WARNING',
        E_PARSE             => 'PARSING ERROR',
        E_NOTICE            => 'NOTICE',
        E_CORE_ERROR        => 'CORE ERROR',
        E_CORE_WARNING      => 'CORE WARNING',
        E_COMPILE_ERROR     => 'COMPILE ERROR',
        E_COMPILE_WARNING   => 'COMPILE WARNING',
        E_USER_ERROR        => 'USER ERROR',
        E_USER_WARNING      => 'USER WARNING',
        E_USER_NOTICE       => 'USER NOTICE',
        E_STRICT            => 'STRICT NOTICE',
        E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR => 'RECOVERABLE ERROR'
    );  

    $VERSION    = isset($CONF['VERSION']) ? $CONF['VERSION'] : 'UNKNOWN';
    $DIR        = MODE == 'INSTALL' ? '..' : '.';   

    fputs($f, '<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->-['.$errorType[$errno].']-['.date('Y.m.d at (H:i:s)',TIMESTAMP).']{'.( isset($USER['id']) ? $USER['id'] : NULL ).'}
    Message: '.$exception->getMessage().'
    File: '.$exception->getFile().'
    Line: '.$exception->getLine().'
    URL: '.PROTOCOL.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']: '').'
    Debug Backtrace:
  '.makebr(str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '.', 
  htmlspecialchars($exception->getTraceAsString()))).'
');

    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>'.(isset($CONF['game_name']) ? $CONF['game_name'].' - ' : '').$errorType[$errno].'</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$DIR.'/styles/css/ingame.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$DIR.'/styles/theme/gow/formate.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body id="overview" class="full">
<table width="666" style="margin-top:100px;">
    <tr>
        <th>Error Administration notified</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Try to reconnect to the game, or wait for error correction.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';
    if($errno === 0) {
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        trigger_error("Exception: ".str_replace("<br>", "\r\n", $errstr)."\r\n\r\n".str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '.', $exception->getTraceAsString()), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    exit;
}
```

Error what is thrown when trying to access one of the pages:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: Undefined offset: 8192 in C:\wamp64\www\eogame\game\includes\GeneralFunctions.php on line 892
( ! ) ErrorException: Undefined offset: 8192 in C:\wamp64\www\eogame\game\includes\GeneralFunctions.php on line 892
```

The line that gets error:

```
fputs($f, '<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->-['.$errorType[$errno].']-['.date('Y.m.d at (H:i:s)',TIMESTAMP).']{'.( isset($USER['id']) ? $USER['id'] : NULL ).'}
```

Part that makes error:

```
$errorType[$errno]
```

Are the problem is in array or i need to change parts of my function that better suits PHP 7, maybe someone can point me in right direction? Thanks

Comment: [Why is "point me in the right direction" is not an actual question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/are-point-me-in-the-right-direction-questions-acceptable)

Comment: Sounds like your `$errorType` array doesn't contain the type of error you're trying to handle. I'll bet you could check that beforehand.

Comment: `8192 E_DEPRECATED`

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php for the other errors it's missing.

Comment: Get core `E_*` constants: `var_dump(array_filter(get_defined_constants(true)["Core"], function($a){return strpos($a, "E_") === 0;}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));`

Comment: Thanks i fix it, and thanks for the link.